# sqlite3 .dump inserts replace function in dump (change from 3.18 to 3.19)

Tags: linux, sqlite

In sqlite3 [3.19.3](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_19_3.html) the dump file produced by `sqlite3 .dump`  or by `sqlite3` with `.mode insert t_objects` (where `t_objects` is the name of a table) followed by `SELECT * FROM t_objects;` uses the `replace` function for newline characters. See sqlite3 file [ext/misc/dbdump.c](http://www2.sqlite.org/cgi/src/finfo?name=ext/misc/dbdump.c) function `output_quoted_escaped_string` near line 370.

But in sqlite3 3.18 the behavior was to output newline characters as is, which I prefer.

So with 3.18 my dump contained:

```
 CREATE TABLE t_objects
   (ob_id VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY ASC NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ob_mtim REAL NOT NULL,
    ob_content TEXT NOT NULL,
    ob_paylkind VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ob_paylinit TEXT NOT NULL,
    ob_paylcontent TEXT NOT NULL);
```

later followed with

```
 INSERT INTO t_objects VALUES('_0UsE4ep7mY5_3M6VTOn9Doe',1497676631.12,'
 ///$c
 
 ','named','c','@NAMEDPROXY: __');
```

but with 3.19.3 the same `INSERT` statement (for the *same* row content) became

```
 INSERT INTO t_objects VALUES('_0UsE4ep7mY5_3M6VTOn9Doe',1497676631.1199998855,
   replace('\n///$c\n\n','\n',char(10)),'named','c','@NAMEDPROXY: __');
```

<sup>(I added a newline after the last comma of the first line for readability here; but it was not there)</sup>

It is a [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_19_3.html) change

> ### Changes carried forward from version 3.19.0 (2017-05-22):
>
> Use replace() instead of char() for escaping newline and carriage-return characters embedded in strings in the `.dump` output from the command-line shell.

But I dislike it (because I had to write a specialized dumping program [dumpsqlmonimelt.cc](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/dumpsqlmonimelt.cc))

Is there some way (e.g. some option or `sqlite3` directive) to get back, using, sqlite 3.19.3, that old sqlite 3.18 behavior and format in dump.

The reason I am asking is that I actually keep that dump in git (e.g. this [mom_user.sql](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/mom_user.sql) file) with the `sqlite3` dump and restore done by git [pre-commit](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/pre-commit-githook.sh) and [post-merge](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/post-merge-githook.sh) hooks. And I really like these newlines characters appearing as-is in dump files (that was one of my reasons to choose [sqlite3](http://sqlite.org/), hence having a `git` friendly dump).

FWIW the `sqlite3` is the one from Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 (package version 3.19.3-3)

#### addenda

It could happen that sqlite 3.20 would improve that issue (at least for `.dump`). See its [release log](https://sqlite.org/draft/releaselog/3_20_0.html) and my [sqlite-user message of July 14<sup>th</sup>](http://mailinglists.sqlite.org/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-users/2017-July/073717.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite3` command-line shell is not considered a part of the SQLite library itself, and has no API stability guarantee.

There is no option to go back to the 3.18 behaviour. You have to revert that change manually, or use your own dumping program.